# Set Spinner selected item by value - casting SpinnerAdapter to ArrayAdapter?

Tags: android, kotlin, spinner

I have a Spinner which is populated by array from strings.xml, user sets it to something, I save it to preferences - I'd like to save the string as I print it in several places further, instead of the position.
Now when the user comes back, I want to set the Spinner to previously selected value.

If I do

```
val myAdapter = mySpinner.adapter as ArrayAdapter<String>
mySpinner.setSelection(myAdapter.getPosition(savedValue))
```

it works, but Studio warns me about unchecked cast. Is there some correct and pretty way to do this? Or do I have to go, create ArrayAdapter from the string resource array and search there?

Comment: The 1st line gives you this warning. Java has to cast your adapter to ArrayAdapter<String> and is complaining about the unsure outcome. If you want to find the position of the savedvalue search the array of strings you created to load the values from strings.xml

Answer (score 0):

```
String[] stringArray = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.stringlist);
val itemPosition = Arrays.asList(stringArray).indexOf(string)
mySpinner.setSelection(itemPosition)
```